# Tinymce activate on double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, mouse

I'm using [Tinymce4 inline editor](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/inline.php). And its just fine, but I need it to activate edition on double click, not on any click or selecting.

I was looking for some documentation or options for this but I havent found anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by `event_root: "#containerId"` configuration option. But at the same time you will need some other JS library like jQuery via which you can add `dblClick` event and prevent normal click event.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to attach a double-click event handler on the editable content that would at that time make the tinymce.init() call. You'll want to use the "auto_focus" setting as well...

```
<div id="editable" ondblclick="init_mce()">
My editable HTML is here
</div>

<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<script>
function init_mce() {
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#editable',
    auto_focus: 'editable'
    // Other settings go here
  });
}
```